# Using Leigh version of S3Wrapper.cfc Can't get past Init

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion, lucee

I am new to S3 and need to use it for image storage.  I found a half dozen versions of an s2wrapper for cf but it appears that the only one set of for v4 is one modified by Leigh

https://gist.github.com/Leigh-/26993ed79c956c9309a9dfe40f1fce29

Dropped in the com directory and created a "test" page that contains the following code:

```
s3 = createObject('component','com.S3Wrapper').init(application.s3.AccessKeyId,application.s3.SecretAccessKey);
```

but got the following error :
[image]

So I changed the line 37 from

`variables.Sv4Util = createObject('component', 'Sv4').init(arguments.S3AccessKey, arguments.S3SecretAccessKey);`

to

`variables.Sv4Util = createObject('component', 'Sv4Util').init(arguments.S3AccessKey, arguments.S3SecretAccessKey);`

Now I am getting:[image]

I feel like going through Leigh code and start changing things is a bad idea since I have lurked here for year an know Leigh's code is solid.

Does any know if there are any examples on how to use this anywhere?  If not what I am doing wrong.  If it makes a difference I am using Lucee 5 and not Adobe's CF engine.

**UPDATE :**

I followed Leigh's directions and the error is now gone.  I am addedsome more code to my test page which now looks like this :

```
<cfscript>
    s3 = createObject('component','com.S3v4').init(application.s3.AccessKeyId,application.s3.SecretAccessKey);

    bucket = "imgbkt.domain.com";
    obj = "fake.ping";
    region = "s3-us-west-1"

    test = s3.getObject(bucket,obj,region);
    writeDump(test);
    test2 = s3.getObjectLink(bucket,obj,region);
    writeDump(test2);

    writeDump(s3);
</cfscript>
```

Regardless of what I put in for bucket, obj or region I get :[image]

JIC I did go to AWS and get new keys:[image]

Leigh if you are still around or anyone how has used one of the s3Wrappers any suggestions or guidance?

**UPDATE #2:**
Even after Alex's help I am not able to get this to work.  The Link I receive from getObjectLink is not valid and getObject never does download an object.  I thought I would try the putObject method

```
test3 = s3.putObject(bucketName=bucket,regionName=region,keyName="favicon.ico");
writeDump(test3);
```

to see if there is any additional information, I received this :[image]

I did find this article https://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html but it is pretty old and since S3 specifically suggests using dots in bucketnames I don't that it is relevant any longer.  There is obviously something I am doing wrong but I have spent hours trying to resolve this and I can't seem to figure out what it might be.

Comment: Bad naming on my part (to differentiate the signature 4 version). It requires two components: the S3 wrapper and Sv4 utility.  A) Save [The S3 Component](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Leigh-/26993ed79c956c9309a9dfe40f1fce29/raw/da1caf605370705a7d258fcddbcb79994af60162/S3Wrapper.cfc) as `S3v4.cfc` and B) [The Signature 4 Utility](https://gist.github.com/Leigh-/a2798584b79fd9072605a4cc7ff60df4#file-sv4util-cfc) as `Sv4.cfc` (both in your `com` directory). Then add `com` to the CFC path on line 38: `variables.Sv4Util = createObject('component', 'com.Sv4').init(...);`

Comment: .. (cont'd) Thanks for the heads up! I will fix things (so it is more clear) tomorrow.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are your expected results for which function calls?

Comment: I am expecting to get the object itself (d/l) from the first call, get the link from the second call or get some type of error neither of which I am getting

Comment: After spending too much time on this I have been able to use all of the built in S3 services in Lucee to do what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a rundown of what the code does:

`getObjectLink` returns a HTTP URL for the file `fake.ping` that is found looking in the bucket `imgbkt.domain.com` of region `s3-us-west-1`. This link is temporary and expires after 60 seconds by default.

`getObject` invokes `getObjectLink` and immediately requests the URL using HTTP GET. The response is then saved to the directory of the `S3v4.cfc` with the filename `fake.ping` by default. Finally the function returns the full path of the downloaded file: `E:\wwwDevRoot\taa\fake.ping`

To save the file in a different location, you would invoke:

```
downloadPath = 'E:\';
test = s3.getObject(bucket,obj,region,downloadPath);
writeDump(test);
```

The HTTP request is synchronous, meaning the file will be downloaded completely when the functions returns the filepath.

If you want to access the actual content of the file, you can do this:

```
test = s3.getObject(bucket,obj,region);

contentAsString = fileRead(test); // returns the file content as string
// or
contentAsBinary = fileReadBinary(test); // returns the content as binary (byte array)

writeDump(contentAsString);
writeDump(contentAsBinary);
```

(You might want to stream the content if the file is large since `fileRead`/`fileReadBinary` reads the whole file into buffer. [Use `fileOpen` to stream the content.](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/fileopen.html)

Does that help you?

Comment: I have added "Update #2" to my original question.  I still think there is something I am doing wrong and after trying a putObject I am getting back more information to support that.